# Show difference between 2 time stamps in seconds and 1/10ths of a second

Tags: google-sheets, time-format

I'm looking for a formula to show the time in seconds and 1/10ths of a second between two time stamped cells (produced using CTRL+SHIFT+:) in a Google sheet. The max time between the cells will be less than 1 hour. To make it easy for people to understand it needs to be in the format 123.4 for 123 seconds and 4 tenths. Could anyone help please

Comment: Share the google sheet or screen short where you are trying this

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract the two times and show the result with a custom format of

```
[ss].0
```

[image]